# Lie algebra of general linear group

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I’m reading through some Lie algebra notes and I have never studied Lie groups at all but it says that $\mathfrak{gl}_n (\mathbb{F})$ denotes the Lie algebra $(M_n (\mathbb{F})  , [\cdot , \cdot ] )$ where $[A, B]=AB - BA $. (Where $L $ is a vector space over $\mathbb{F}$).

A few pages on it says let $L$ be a Lie algebra, then consider $\mathfrak{gl}(L) $. My question is, is this ok? Don’t we have to consider $\mathfrak{gl}(\mathbb{F})$ where $\mathbb{F} $ is the field which $L$ is over as a vector space.

Comment: For any $\mathbb F$-vector space $V$, one defines the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{gl}(V):= (End_{\mathbb F}(V), [\cdot, \cdot])$ with $[A,B] =A\circ B - B\circ A$. That's the basis-free version of what you have, or in other words, if $\dim(V)=n$ then any choice of basis gives an iso $\mathfrak{gl}(V) \simeq \mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb F)$. --- Since a Lie algebra $L$ is in particular a vector space, one *can* also consider $\mathfrak{gl}(L)$, e.g. for the adjoint representation $L \rightarrow \mathfrak{gl}(L)$. Without context it's impossible to tell if in your case it's a misprint or intentional.

Comment: Of course if $L$ is already, e.g., $L=\mathfrak{gl}_3(\mathbb F)$, then something like $\mathfrak{gl}(\mathfrak{gl}_3(\mathbb F))$ looks funny, but it's consistent and actually a good reminder that we're dealing with "bigger" matrices. (Here $L$ would have dimension $9$ so $\mathfrak{gl}(L)$ would have dimension $81$.)

Comment: Certainly you know the space ${\rm End}(V)$ for a vector space. There is no need that $V=\Bbb F$ here, too. So your question can be answered already on the level of vector spaces.